# Trying to rewrite the following algorithm in C# that merges two arrays based off a common key

Tags: c#, dictionary

Given A and B of different lengths that will *always* share a common key, X:

```
A = [
  {X: "a", Y: 5},
  {X: "b", Y: 10},
  {X: "c", Y: 15}
];

B = [
  {X: "a", Z: 5},
  {X: "d", Z: 10}
];
```

Produces the following array:

```
C = [    
  {X: "a", Y: 5, Z: 5},
  {X: "b", Y: 10},
  {X: "c", Y: 15},
  {X: "d", Z: 10}
]
```

Where keys with the same X value are combined.

In Javascript the algorithm follows:

```
var C = A.concat(B), temp = {}, result = [];

C.forEach(function(o, i) {
   temp[o.X] = temp[o.X] || o;
   for(var k in o) temp[o.X][k] = o[k];
});

for(var i in temp) result.push(temp[i]);

console.log(result);
```

---

I am trying to recreate the following algorithm in C#:

```
public static void List<Dictionary<string, object>> (List<Dictionary<string, object>> A, List<Dictionary<string, object>> B) {

  List<Dictionary<string, object>> result;
  var d = A.Concat(B).ToList();

  Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> temp = new Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>();

  for (int i = 0; i < d.Count(); i++)
  {
     var key = d[i]["X"];
     if (!temp.ContainsKey(key)) temp[key] = d[i];

     foreach (var k in d[i]) temp[key][k.Key] = k.Value; 
  }

   foreach(var k in temp)
   {
      result.Insert(temp[k]);
   }

   return result;
}
```

However I am struggling with creating it, primarily I get the error:

> Message = "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

```
foreach (var k in d[i]) temp[key][k.Key] = k.Value;
```

How can I successfully complete the algorithm?

Comment: Using `object` and `dynamic` are really bad ways to code C# unless you absolutely need to. I assume you meant "preceding algorithm" ?

Comment: you cant modify a collection when youre iterating through it, so'd need to make a temp \ anonymous object or create a new instance of an object

Comment: Make a class, struct or tuppel that can hold both values (it appears to be 2 Integers). Make a Dictionary <key, customtype>. Transfer the data. Done. I agree that Dynamic, Object and all other disolutions of type safety should be avoided. Strong Typisation is your friend, not your enemy.

Comment: I don't see where you are modifying a collection your are iterating, so what line causes the error?

Comment: @SimonPrice: "you cant modify a collection when youre iterating through it" **Not** correct. You can not change a collection while you itterate over it through foreach. Foreach does not use collections. It uses Enumeartors. And Enumerators (have to) break if you change the underlying collection. Stop using foreach/Enumerators and you can change them as you see fit.

Comment: Oh god, look at all the `dynamic`!  My Eyes!

Comment: Attempting to use your code, it isn't compilable. Can you post the code that actually generated the message, or fix your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a (fixed) C# implementation of the Javascript code. There are a few improvements, but that main issue is probably that you are not creating a copy of the `Dictionary` you assign to `temp` when the key is not already there. Also, in both programs there is no reason to copy over the keys you just assigned when the key is missing.

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> Merge2(List<Dictionary<string, object>> A, List<Dictionary<string, object>> B) {
    var D = A.Concat(B);

    var temp = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();

    foreach (var d in D) {
        var key = (string)d["X"];
        if (temp.ContainsKey(key))
            foreach (var kv in d)
                temp[key][kv.Key] = kv.Value;
        else
            temp[key] = new Dictionary<string, object>(d);
    }

    return new List<Dictionary<string, object>>(temp.Values);
}
```

A perhaps more C# implementation would use LINQ and an extension.

Here is an extension to merge two `Dictionary<string,object>` objects into one that treats a null value as an empty `Dictionary`:

```
public static class DictionaryExt {
    public static Dictionary<TK, TV> Merge<TK, TV>(this Dictionary<TK, TV> src, Dictionary<TK, TV> add) {
        var merged = (src != null) ? new Dictionary<TK, TV>(src) : new Dictionary<TK, TV>();
        if (add != null)
            foreach (var kv in add)
                if (merged.ContainsKey(kv.Key))
                    merged[kv.Key] = kv.Value;
                else
                    merged.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);

        return merged;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately LINQ doesn't include a full outer join implementation, so here are a set of extension methods that implement a full outer join:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> LeftOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TLeft> leftItems,
    IEnumerable<TRight> rightItems,
    Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector,
    Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector,
    Func<TKey, TLeft, TRight, TResult> resultSelector) {

    return from left in leftItems
           join right in rightItems on leftKeySelector(left) equals rightKeySelector(right) into rightj
           from right in rightj.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select resultSelector(leftKeySelector(left), left, right);
}

public static IEnumerable<TResult> RightAntiSemiJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TLeft> leftItems,
    IEnumerable<TRight> rightItems,
    Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector,
    Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector,
    Func<TKey, TLeft, TRight, TResult> resultSelector) where TLeft : class {

    var hashLK = (from l in leftItems select leftKeySelector(l)).ToHashSet();
    return rightItems.Where(r => !hashLK.Contains(rightKeySelector(r))).Select(r => resultSelector(rightKeySelector(r), (TLeft)null, r));
}

public static IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TLeft> leftItems,
    IEnumerable<TRight> rightItems,
    Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector,
    Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector,
    Func<TKey, TLeft, TRight, TResult> resultSelector) where TLeft : class {

    return leftItems.LeftOuterJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector).Concat(leftItems.RightAntiSemiJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector));
}
```

Now the code to marge the two lists is pretty straight forward:

```
var result = A.FullOuterJoin(B,
                             a => (string)a["X"],
                             b => (string)b["X"],
                             (k, a, b) => a.Merge(b))
              .ToList();
```